# Buchsbaum-Eisenbud-Horrocks conjecture for finitely generated modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Someone know a version for conjecture of Buchsbaum-Eisenbud-Horrocks whithout the assumptions that
the $R$-module $M$  has length finite?